# Hover Menu From Non-Child Div

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a div that I need to function like a hover menu. I cannot make it a child element (because of how I'm using it in a Wordpress theme). The li menu item that triggers the hover has an id of #menu-item-183. The div I need to appear is #const-training-menu.

I have the following code, which almost works.

```
        //hides the div on page load
        $('#const-training-menu').hide();

        //show menu div when li is hovered
        $('#menu-item-183').hover(function () {
            $('#const-training-menu').show();
        }, function () {
                $('#const-training-menu').hide();
        });

        //keeps menu div visible when the menu div is hovered
        $('#const-training-menu').hover(function () {
            $('#const-training-menu').show();
        }, function () {
            $('#const-training-menu').hide();
        });
```

However, this functionality is a little buggy. You have to move from the li item to the visible div very quickly and time it just right to keep it visible. I've tried adding a setTimeout to the hover hide to try to allow time to get to the div, but that doesn't seem to help or work. Any thoughts?

If you'd like to see this in development, visit http://naspweb.com/ and hover over the CONSTRUCTION TRAINING / CERTIFICATIONS menu option.

---

Edit

---

I tried this based on the suggestions below, but the submenu still doesn't stay visible.

```
$(document).ready(function () {                        
        $('#const-training-menu').hide(); //initial hide
              var isHovered = false;
        $('#menu-item-183').hover(function () {
            $('#const-training-menu').show();
        }, function () {
            if(isHovered)return; //allows other event handler to override this mouseout
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#const-training-menu').hide();
            }, 1000);
        });

        $('#const-training-menu').hover(function () {
            isHovered = true;
            $('#const-training-menu').show();
        }, function () {
            isHovered = false;
            $('#const-training-menu').hide();
        });
});
```

Comment: can you tell me what is `$('#menu-item-183').hover(function () {
            $('#const-training-menu').show();
        }, function () {
                $('#const-training-menu').hide();` command for ? I mean why are you using both show and hide functions like that ?

Comment: It is specifying both the mousein and mouseout event handlers.

Comment: but cant we just hide the `#const-training-menu` by default using `display:none` and when it hovers and it shows..and when it mouseOUt, it will automatically hide ?

Comment: no because it needs to be shown on two different conditions, the menu item is hovered followed by the menu itself being hovered

Answer (score 0):

I would try to setup some kind of an override flag for the mouseout portion of the menu item event handler; something like this:

```
$(function(){
    var isHovered = false;

    $('#menu-item-183').hover(function () {
            $('#const-training-menu').show();
        }, function () {
            if(isHovered)return; //allows other event handler to override this mouseout
            $('#const-training-menu').hide();
        });

        $('#const-training-menu').hover(function () {
            isHovered = true;
        }, function () {
        isHovered = false;
            $('#const-training-menu').hide();
        });
});
```

I haven't actually tested this but my only concern is the first mouse out could trigger before the flag is set. The timeout you mention would solve this issue if it does occur.